# Issue with hoverIntent and slideUp slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a group of `<li>`s that are headings in a slider. Each heading has sub-headings contained in `.sub-menu` with the current menu that is already selected being `.current-menu-item`. I would like the current item to be present upon load. I am currently calling this with:

```
var myPath = window.location.pathname;

console.log(myPath);

if(myPath == '/thing/'){
   $('#menu-item-1 .sub-menu').slideToggle("1000");
};
if(myPath == '/other-thing1/'){
   $('#menu-item-2 .sub-menu').slideToggle("1000");
};
if(myPath == '/other-thing2/'){
   $('#menu-item-3 .sub-menu').slideToggle("1000");
};
```

This causes the current page's `.sub-menu` to display whenever I'm on that page.

The goal is to get the nav so that when I initially load the page, the sub-menu for the page displays. Then, when I mouse over the other menus, the sub menu for the current menu slides up. Then, when I mouse out of any heading, the sub-menus of the `.current-menu-item` slides down again. Below is what I have so far, which gets me pretty close, but the `.current-menu-item` isn't sliding up again.

```
$(".aside-section-content ul li").each(function(){              
if($(this).children('.sub-menu').length){ 
    $(this).hoverIntent({
        interval: 50,
        over: function navHoverInDrop () { 
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideDown(300).prev('a').css({'background-image':'none'});
        },
        timeout: 250,
        out: function navHoverOutDrop () { 
            $(this).not('.current-menu-item').children('.sub-menu').slideUp(300).prev('a').css({'background':"url('uploads/plus.png') no-repeat center right 13px"});
        }            
    });
}
});
```

I've been able to get some variations that have gotten close, but haven't yet gotten it bug free. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: can you post your question in jsfiddle? it makes easier to answer..!

Comment: Sounds like you're after something called `persistent navigation`.  This is typically achieved on the server by adding a class to the appropriate nav item or body tag so it's targetable.  Search for persistent nav and you should get a ton of hits.